# Current Sys.time() in the rendered table

Tags: r, shiny

I am rendering a table in Shiny and I want to have `Sys.time()` in the first column of the table. The Sys.time() function should be executed when the user press Render. The objecitve is to track the time user created the row in the table. I have the following code,

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Input table"),
  sidebarPanel(
    
    textInput(inputId = "autodate", 
              label = "Timestamp", 
              value = "Sys.time()"),
    
    textInput(inputId = "State",
              label = "State",
              value = "State"),
    
    selectInput("shot", "Drinks",
                list(`Shot Type` = list("Beer", "Whisky", "Vodka"))),
    
    actionButton("button", "Export file")),
  
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", tableOutput(outputId = "table")))))


server <- function(input, output){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    df = data.frame(
      Autodate = numeric(),
      State = character(),
      ShotType = character()
    )
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    rv$df <- rbind(rv$df, data.frame(Autodate = input$autodate,
                                     State = input$State,
                                     ShotType = input$shot
                                     ))

    output$table <-renderTable({
      rv$df})
    #
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here the Sys.time() is not producing any output in the rendered table. Anyone can help me to fix the issue?

Comment: If you are referring to this: value = "Sys.time()", by enclosing the function in quotes it is becoming a string and not a function.  Try removing the “s

Comment: I disagree: if you intend to use the time when the user pressed `input$button`, then you need a reactive component that depends on that, and then _there_ add `Sys.time()` as a column. First, there's no need for `Sys.time()` in an `input` if it will always be added automatically. Second, move `output$table <- ...` _outside_ of the `observeEvent(input$button, ...)`. If you need it to only change on button-press, that's fine, but it should likely be on its own. (I've not seen much utility in _nesting_ observe/reactive blocks.)

Comment: My guess is that you should add `Sys.time()` to `rv$df` inside of your `observeEvent`